# Stop embed from vanishing on refresh

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP page embeded in an  tag, and in the PHP page is a meta refresh. Every time it refreshes the text in the embed blinks away for a second, is there any way to make it so that it only updates the embed box instead of refreshing it and making the text vanish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it is to change the method completely: instead of using `<iframe>`, you should request this PHP script with AJAX, and then update the area content with Javascript.

For example,
1. assuming you have jQuery installed ([howto](http://goo.gl/O0JHC)).
2. assuming that "area" is a `<div id="area"></div>`
3. assuming you have to call the `script.php` to load the content
4. assuming the refresh rate = 5 seconds

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        setInterval(function(){ 
            $("#area").load("script.php");
        }, 5000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that. Ive never done JavaScript or jQuery before so Im a bit weary. I tried what you said, and now when it refreshes it reloads the entire page, including the second embed thats below it.

Comment: I still see meta refresh there. Where's the jQuery?

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot to remove the refresh from the included file, so it was refreshing twice. removed that and its working perfectly. thanks for telling me.